# Cached plan must not change result type

Tags: postgresql, pg-jdbc

Our service team is getting the error *Cached plan must not change result type* sometimes when I modify the length of a column or add a new column in the table.

I tried solutions mentioned on Stack Overflow like [Postgres: "ERROR: cached plan must not change result type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783813/postgres-error-cached-plan-must-not-change-result-type)

I have tried `autosave=conservative` to resolve this issue but still, I am able to reproduce this issue. I used below JDBC connection string

```
jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://172.16.244.10:5432/testdb?autosave=conservative
```

why is this property not working in my case?

Also, I tested with `prepareThreshold=0` and its working fine. But I think it will impact performance because it will never use client-side prepared statements.

I just want to know the best solution to avoid this error.

Comment: Can you update the exact error