# I need help understanding why JUnit tests throw a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cached plan must not change result type`

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, junit, flyway

I have a Spring application with a bunch of integration tests that use TestContainers and JUnit. I create a `protected static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14-alpine")` that I then use in my tests, and I have a method annotated with `@BeforeEach` that cleans the DB and then re-apply the migration.

Everything was working fine until I added a new migration script to my application:

```sql
CREATE TYPE user_state_enum AS ENUM ('ACTIVE', 'DELETED');

ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN user_state TYPE user_state_enum; -- this was a text field before
```

and suddenly I started getting some fails in my integration tests. It consistently fails on some tests while executing `userRepository.findByUserId(userId)` with the error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cached plan must not change result type`. I modified my entity Java class according to [this tutorial](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-enum-mappings/#Customized_Mapping_to_a_Database-Specific_Enum_Type), so I created a class that extends from `org.hibernate.type.EnumType` and implemented the `nullSafeSet` method.

I managed to solve the problem already by setting in my `application-test.yaml` the following property:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        preparedStatementCacheQueries: 0
```

but I am still struggling to understand why this is happening. I read on some other SO posts that it might be due to Flyway altering the DB while I execute some `select` queries in a test, but afaik Flyway should be done migrating the DB once a test is executed, and the next migration should not start until the tests is done executing. I have an idea that it might be due to the fact that I delete and recreate the whole schema after every test, but I never encountered this behaviour in any other integration test I've written.

Answer (score 0):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784421/546757, a user posted that the issue was solved by adding "?preparedStatementCacheQueries=0" to the JDBC URL to disable prepared statements caching. That user claims that the error is due to Flyway clearing and recreating the schema between caching the statement and reusing it.

I'm not sure if the explanation is accurate, but adding "?preparedStatementCacheQueries=0" to the JDBC URL worked for me.